# Detect when finger dragging UIButton overlaps UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to drag a `UIButton` around the screen. The idea is that the user can drag it over a folder to insert it in the folder (like iOS icons). This code I found works fine if I want to detect when the button overlaps with the image:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *) touches {
if(CGRectIntersectsRect([imageViewA frame], [imageViewB frame]) {
  NSLog(@"Do something.");
}
  }
```

But since the button is big and there are more images one next to another, it may happen that the button overlaps with both of them. I therefore want to detect when the actual user finger holding the `UIButton` overlaps with the image to trigger the right action. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGestureRecognizer` will recognize the pan and when it ends, you can use [`locationInView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/locationInView%3a) to find the finger's position in the button's super view.  You can then see if they are overlapping with [`CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint):

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint fingerPoint = [recognizer locationInView:someImageView.superview];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(someImageView.frame, fingerPoint)) {
              NSLog(@"Do something");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I forgot to say but I am using if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {  not touches ended...

Comment: with CGRectContainsPoint how can I set the image I want to check for?

Comment: I've changed the code to reflect its use as the target of a gesture recognizer and to include an image view reference.  If you need to check multiple images, you can loop over a collection of them and move `CGRectContainsPoint()` into the body of that loop.

Comment: if I need to check more than one I can just repeat the code changing someImageView...

Comment: but the someImageView needs to be the same??

Comment: `someImageView` should be your drop target.  If you have more than one, you should loop over all of the drop targets and then do the `CGRectContainsPoint()` test against each of them.

Comment: For some reason its not working. I changed someImageView to my image

Comment: and recognizer to UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer;

Comment: Works fine now, I used (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender instead of recognizer